# SVN Getting The Count Of Revisions Of A Repository

Tags: qt, batch-file, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I am curently working on a Qt c++ project that is basically printing all the commit log messages between a specific SVN Repository's 2 specific revision's (User enters the repo and the revisions).

I need to get the count of revisions in a repo URL.

I want to do this on Windows 10 so I guess a batch command could be pretty useful.

I am using Visual SVN Server and Tortoise SVN.

(My Qt version is 5.11.1 if it would be necessary)

I have a batch script that does print all the logs between 2 specific revisions to a .txt file.

It is like this:

```
@ECHO OFF

REM This Script Takes all the logs between a given repository's 2 specific revision.

REM Below, we store the first parameter which is the URL of the Repository that is wanted.
SET urlOfRepository=%1

REM Below, we store the second parameter which is the first revision that is wanted.
SET firstRevision=%2

REM Below, we store the third parameter which is the second revision that is wanted.
SET secondRevision=%3

REM Below is the command for getting all the log messages between the first and the second revision that is wanted in the wanted repository and printing to a .txt file.
svn log -r %firstRevision%:%secondRevision% --limit %secondRevision% %urlOfRepository% > svnLog.txt

EXIT /B 0
```

I would be glad if someone can help me.

I can clarify the question more if it is needed so please do not hesitate to contact me via comments.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks to Kostix the answer is:

```
svn info -r HEAD --show-item revision %URL%
```

And I have written a script to solve my problem. Here it is:

```
@ECHO OFF

REM This Script writes the revision count of a specific SVN repository

REM Below, we store the first parameter which is the URL of the Repository that is wanted.
SET urlOfRepository=%1

REM Below, is the command that returns the count of revisions in the specifically given SVN repository and writes to a .txt file
svn info -r HEAD --show-item revision %urlOfRepository% > svnCountOfRepoRevisions.txt

EXIT /B 0
```

Comment: Add the define to the makefile `DEFINES += "SVN_REV=\"\\\"$(shell svnversion -n)\\\"\""` it will give you the current svn revision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to do it that complicated—a mere

```
svn log -r HEAD:1 %URL%
```

should work.

The special `HEAD` revision is automatically the last one in the repository, and the revision 1 is the first one (obviously).

Subversion is smart enough to skip revisions in which the URL does not
exist, so, say, if it was added in revision 42, `svn log` won't complain there is no URL in the revision range [41…1].

---

You can obtain more info by running

```
svn help log
```

in your console window.

Comment: Oh, and you might also use the `BASE` revision — just in case the URL does not exist anymore at `HEAD` (which may be past `BASE`).

Comment: @ kostix My Script does print the output of the command you wrote( svn log -r HEAD:1 %URL%). Thank you for your answer though. I just need the value of HEAD so I can list the revisions in a QListWidget.

Comment: You can do `svn info -r HEAD --show-item revision %URL%` tnen.